# vue client file direct download from node js server doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

Alright, so I've been trying for 2 days now to send an audio file as a direct download in the browser from a node js backend (port 8081) to a vue js client frontend (port 8080) on http request (using axios).

There are some topics on this in stack overflow but none of them fixed my problem, I probably made an error somewhere but I just can't seem to see where exactly.

My browser/client receives the response but doesnt translate this to a direct download, here's how it looks:

```
{data: "ID3#TSSELavf57.71.100���…UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:8081/api/tracks/download/5df305bc6cea85c8eac5d3e6", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: "ID3#TSSELavf57.71.100���..."
headers: {cache-control: "public, max-age=0", content-length: "9775064", content-type: "audio/mpeg", last-modified: "Fri, 13 Dec 2019 03:30:04 GMT"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Do i need to setup a proxy, i'm not sure I quite understand how to do this correctly ? I've really been trying hard to get it to work lol

Here are the codes:

*node.js server download route*

```
router.get('/download/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const tracks = await loadTracksCollection();
  var id = new mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.id);
  var track = await tracks.findOne({ _id: id });
  var trackPath = String(track.path);
  var trackName = String(track.user + ' - ' + track.name + '.mp3');
  res.download(trackPath, trackName, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return ;
    } else {
    tracks.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $inc: { downloadCount: 1 } });
    // return res.status(200).send('The download should start ...')
    }
  });
});
```

*vue.js button component*

```
<template>
  <v-btn @click="download" depressed block color="accent"><unicon name="import" fill="white" /></v-btn>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  props: {
    fileId: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    download() {
      axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_AUDIO_API_URL + '/api/tracks/download/' + this.fileId)
           .then(response => {
             console.log(response)
           })
           .catch(error => {
             console.error(error)
           })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

let me know if anymore code is needed !

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, seems like a complex subject, but I found my solution tho here you go:

```
      this.$axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: // ur backend api url,
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })
        .then(response => {
          var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers['content-type']})
          var link = document.createElement('a')
          link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          link.download = // name the downloaded file
          link.click()
        })
        .catch(error => { 
          // whatever
        })
        .finally(() => {
          // whatever
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the responseType in axios...

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: process.env.VUE_APP_AUDIO_API_URL + '/api/tracks/download/' + this.fileId,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(response => {
   console.log(response.data)
}).catch(error => {
   console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me ! Just tried this and the dev tools now console this:
ArrayBuffer(440651) {} ... (with a bunch of int arrays)
but no direct download happening